# Integrating Flex/Bison with external program

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm working on an intelligent agent model that requires, as input, a list of events.  The events come from the output of another model and are in a (large) text file.  The text file is a list of all events (including unnecessary events that I don't care about), so I've written a scanner using flex that can find the useful bits.  The framework for the intelligent agent model is already written in C++.

Each event is timestamped and contains a large amount of information about the event.  The format of the input file is constant, so I really have no need to check the syntax.  I don't know if Bison will actually offer me any advantages, because the grammar is actually pretty simple.  There's no real variation.

I just need a way to place each event (and all the information from that event) onto a stack.  The intelligent agent acts on each event chronologically, so I need the program to scan the entire input file, then place each event onto a stack in reverse order (the first event in the input file should be the last event pushed onto the stack).  That will allow the intelligent agent to pop the events off the stack and deal with them one at a time.

My thought is that bison won't help me much, because the grammar is simply a matter of listing all of the tokens sequentially.  It'd basically look like this:

```
eventlist: /* nothing */
| eventlist event EOL
;

event: token1 token2 token3 ... tokenN-1 tokenN
```

Here's a small snippet of the input file, so you can see what I mean:

> Scenario Event Time:                              DAY 1 00:00:00
>   [DATA FUSION EVENT]                               New Track Formed
>   Summary
>   Actual Target:                                    RF HQ
>   Fusion Center Location:                           CVN Enterprise_0
>   Fusion Center Name:                               DEFAULT FUSION
>   Perceived Target
>   Perceived Identification:                         Unknown
>   Perceived Classification:                         Unknown
>   Operating Medium:                                 Land

I have a few questions:

1) How do I integrate the scanner generated by flex with the larger program that already exists?
2) Will bison offer any advantages or am I best off simply writing my own program to put all the tokens on a data structure and put them on the stack?
2a) If bison is better, then that solves question 1, but then how do I call bison from within my program and then have bison return a pointer to the stack so the program can use it?

//Edited: I've figured out how to call flex from an external C++ program.  I have been unable, so far, to create a bison program that will do what I want, though (namely, return a pointer to a stack of events).

Comment: Update: I'm using Windows and the project is currently programmed in Visual Studio 2008.  Up to this point the scanner has been generated via command line and is a standalone program.

Comment: You could also have a look at boost spirit. I never used bison but it was a simple task to transform a bison grammar to spirit. So maybe this helps you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If your grammar is that simple then using a parser seems overkill. Just process each line and scan the tokens into a collection.

Why do you think you need a parser?

Comment: Because I couldn't find any documentation on interfacing directly with flex without Yacc/Bison.  All the docs I could find assume you're using Yacc/Bison, so the instructions are geared in that direction.

Comment: Ok. So can't you just call yylex() to invoke the scanner?

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to return something useful.  Is there a way to get yylex() to return something useful?  I can call yylex() externally, but I need it to return either a pointer to a stack, or some other useful data structure so the intelligent agent can actually DO something with the tokens.

Comment: Well, it's a while since I used it, but I thought the idea was that as and when each token is recognised it invokes an action defined by you. Here it would seem sensible to push the token onto a vector, and when you hit the end-of-line token push the vector onto the stack. So yylex() won't return anything - it's all done through side-effects.